# How to take the Nth item from a chest?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I dont know if it is possible, but I wanted to ask how can I take the Nth item from a chest? Like I have 7 items in chest in 7 slots and I want take the 4th. Hopper always takes the first one. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Is simply placing the first 3 items back in an option?

Comment: ok that coud work, but if I want to take for example the 30th item, then it would be a bit complex :/

Comment: Is the 4th item alwaysthe same item. Is it different to all other items in the chest?

Comment: no, it can be chest full of iron helmets, wooden swords, etc. but can contain also mixes

Comment: Assuming you just replace the items taken out not needed, would it matter if the items replaced were in the same order?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think there is any way to do this. The hopper will always take the first item in the chest.

You could make a complicated redstone machine to take a certain amount of items out if the chest until it gets to the item you want, and then take out the next item and move it elsewhere though.

I hope this helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

If this is for using it's "fullness" (I don't know the real word :I) for a signal, I suggest using a filter, in which the hopper's other contents would be unstackable with what you're putting in. If not, please see other answers.

Hopefully this helped,
Dragon